# Running Python script over multiple directories and multiple files

Tags: bash, python

Here is my command line for `python`:

```
python script.py -a .faa -n .fna
```

I have a directory containing multiple directories. Out of these multiple directories, there could be 1 or more folders.

In these 1 or more folders, I need to run my python script on the `.faa` and `.fna` files.

How do I do this?

Example tree:

```
Staph1 ----> [CO1, CO2] ----> [.fna, .faa] from CO1, [.fna, .faa] from CO2

Staph2 ----> [CO6] ----> [.fna, .faa] from CO6
```

My Python script will use the inputs `.fna` and `.faa` and output within the folder. Also the folder and directory are synonymous.

Comment: Did you code `script.py`? Why not use `os.walk` to navigate the directory from within `script.py`?

Comment: There are over 4000 genomes, each containing 1 or more contigs.  would have to use my command line 4000+ times just to get the files i need.

Comment: You use both `folder` and `directory` in your question.  Is there a difference between those two things?  If so, what is the difference?  Also, please edit your question to include a portion of an example directory structure for us to look at.

Comment: A tree representing the directory hierarchy would be nice.

Comment: @Jeff does `script.py` takes file names or directories? Do `.fna` and `.faa` come in pairs?

Comment: It takes file names. For example I have a folder. Let's pick Staph1 folder. Under Staph1 folder there could be folder CO1 and CO2. Under these folders there will be a .fna and a .faa file. I want to run my script on the .fna and .faa file in the CO1 folder and I would also like to run my script on the .fna and .faa file in the CO2 folder. Once this is complete, then I want to move onto the next parent folder, which would be Staph2. And so on

Comment: Why not wrap it in the bash find command?

Answer (score 0):

I think this should help:

The script will use `os.walk`, as @1_CR suggested, and will call `hello_world.py` script with the path to both files when `fna` and `faa` files exist together (i.e. in same direcotry).

```
import glob, os

def scanfolder():
    for path, dirs, files in os.walk('/home/shadowe/test1/test1/'):
        flag_faa = 0
        flag_fna = 0
        for f in files:
            if f.endswith('.faa'):
                flag_faa  = 1
                faa_file_path = os.path.join(path,f)
            if f.endswith('.fna'):
                flag_fna = 1
                fna_file_path = os.path.join(path,f)
            if flag_faa == 1 and flag_fna == 1:
                print "Calling script"
                os.system("python hello_world.py" + " -a "+ faa_file_path + " -b " + fna_file_path)
                flag_faa  = 0
                flag_fna  = 0


scanfolder()
```

Second script:

```
import sys

print "Hello World"
print "This argument passing qualifies " + sys.argv[1] + " "  + sys.argv[2] + " " + sys.argv[3] + " " + sys.argv[4]
```

Output:

```
$ python test.py 
Calling script
Hello World
This argument passing qualifies -a /home/shadowe/test1/test1/test2/test3/two.faa -b     /home/shadowe/test1/test1/test2/test3/two.fna
Calling script
Hello World
This argument passing qualifies -a /home/shadowe/test1/test1/test6/test7/four.faa -b /home/shadowe/test1/test1/test6/test7/five.fna
```

Comment: No such file or directory: 'CP003033.faa', is there a way to specify the path?

Comment: @Jeff is that from your `script.py`?

Comment: @Jeff do you need to pass file names as well?

Comment: Yes I need to pass in 2 file names.

Comment: For example: python myscript.py -a .faa -b .fna

Comment: @Jeff I edited my answer to include both file names as an argument, pls check. Though with out seeing `script.py` it's tough to guess how it works. In your first example you had `-n` now there is `-b`,   these will need to be changed in the script above as needed.